# Can one script signal the execution of another, but delay the start until it has finished?

Tags: scripting, process

I need one script to initiate the execution of another script, but the second script should not begin execution until the rest of the first one has completed for a second or two.

The order would be:

1. Start script A.
2. Script A does something to say that script B should execute.
3. Script A finishes.
4. A second or two pass.
5. Script B begins executing.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's keeping you from appending `sleep 2; exec scriptB` to the end of `scriptA`?

Comment: I need script B to execute after script A has completed. It cannot start until script A is no longer running. More details: This is within FileMaker Pro Advanced on macOS. FileMaker needs to do some preparation by executing one Python script. That's script A. Script B is an AppleScript that uses interface scripting to control FileMaker's menus and windows. That can't happen if FileMaker is running a script. The menus aren't available. So first Python needs to do its prep, then some brief time needs to pass, then AppleScript needs to do its work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it in shell scripts; someone else would have to answer in Python.

```
$ cat scriptA
#!/bin/sh
echo begin script A
(sleep 2; nohup ./scriptB 2>/dev/null) &
echo end script A at $(date)
$ cat scriptB
#!/bin/sh
date > scriptB.dat
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./scriptA
begin script A
end script A at Sun Nov 26 20:46:10 EST 2017
$ sleep 2
$ cat scriptB.dat
Sun Nov 26 20:46:12 EST 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Can the AppleScript be running while the shell code does its thing? If so maybe

```
do shell script "pathtoyourcodehere"
delay 3
display dialog "fmpro interface foo here"
```